# MySQL connection lost on complex query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing an app (using CodeIgniter) that needs to retrieve trips using a fairly complex query.  Here is an example of it:

```
SELECT *,   CONCAT(`u1`.`city`,', ', `u1`.`country_id`) as `from_city`, 
            CONCAT(`u2`.`city`,', ', `u2`.`country_id`) as `to_city` 
FROM trips 
LEFT JOIN `cities` as `u1` ON (`u1`.`id`=`from_city`) 
LEFT JOIN `cities` as `u2` ON (`u2`.`id`=`to_city`) 
WHERE trip_id 
IN (SELECT trip_id 
    FROM stops 
    WHERE city_id = 7583 
    AND trip_id 
    IN (SELECT trip_id 
        FROM stops 
        WHERE trip_id 
        IN (SELECT trip_id 
            FROM stops 
            WHERE city_id=7565))) 
            ORDER BY departure_date;
```

It used to work fine until today.  It involves 3 tables (trips, stops and cities). The trips and stops tables has not grown much since started testing, maybe from 200 to 300 records.

If I test within the CodeIgniter app I get a 2006 or a 2013 'Lost connection to MySQL server...' error. If I go and query using NaviCat I get the same "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" message.

To better illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish here is how the tables look like:

Trips (not all columns shown)

[image: trips table]

Stops

[image: all columns shown]

Cities (not all columns shown)

[image: cities table]

Basically freighters insert trips and detail their stops and then agencies will search among the available trips. So if a freighter posts a trip that goes A->B->C->D->E, another freighter posts a trip going K->H->E->D->C both trips should show up when an agent looks for C->E.  The 'ordinal' column in the stops table is the way I later filter out trips that are in the wrong direction.

What can be extending the response time that much?  How can I rewrite this query to make it faster?

Comment: Most likely this query is timing out...Why in the world are you doing a triple nested `in` clause?! That's **horribly** inefficient..

Comment: 3 levels of nesting in the `WHERE` is probably killing performance. Please post a sample of rows from the `trips,cities` tables, together with a sample of what the expected query output should be.

Comment: try to do joins whenever you can. nested `IN` subqueries are horribly inefficient. `IN` subqueries will run on every single row when doing a match.

Comment: @khuderm Isn't that just for correlated subqueries?

Comment: @Uueerdo you are correct. Didn't realize OP's query was uncorrelated. Just saw subqueries

Comment: Thank you all for your interest in this question.  I've just extended it and included more info on the tables and overall objective. @mituw16 yes, I've been reading about and seen both against and supporting nested IN clauses.  I guess I had to feel the pain and learn the hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your query right it looks like you're trying to retrieve all trips between the two cities 7583 and 7565.

If so the query below should return the same result and be a bit more efficient:

```
SELECT *,   CONCAT(u1.city,', ', u1.country_id) as from_city, 
            CONCAT(u2.city,', ', u2.country_id) as to_city 
FROM trips t1
LEFT JOIN cities as u1 ON (u1.id=from_city) 
LEFT JOIN cities as u2 ON (u2.id=to_city) 
JOIN (
    SELECT trip_id FROM stops t1 
    WHERE city_id IN (7583, 7565)
    GROUP BY trip_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT city_id) = 2
) x ON t1.trip_id = x.trip_id 
ORDER BY departure_date;
```

Or maybe I totally misunderstood what it is you're trying to do, in which case I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you!  You got it right and this query is a lot faster. I have never used HAVING even knowing it exists. I'll practice more with it to keep my tools sharpened.

Comment: @zJorge With proper keys (and indexes) set up this should perform ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can re-write your query to

```
SELECT 
  *,   
  CONCAT(`u1`.`city`,', ', `u1`.`country_id`) as `from_city`, 
  CONCAT(`u2`.`city`,', ', `u2`.`country_id`) as `to_city` 
FROM trips 
LEFT JOIN `cities` as `u1` ON (`u1`.`id`=`from_city`) 
LEFT JOIN `cities` as `u2` ON (`u2`.`id`=`to_city`) 
INNER JOIN stops as `stops` ON trips.trip_id = stops.trip_id
WHERE stops.city_id IN (7583, 7565) -- all stops in this 2 cities
;
```

This should run quite fast-ish if you can use proper indices...

Comment: You might need to add a `COUNT` and `HAVING thatCount = 2` since the original task seems to want trips that "stop" in both city_id values.

Comment: Thank @Benvorth but this query is returning trips with either first or second city.  The result should only include trips with both stops.